# Looping over array continuously with timer

Tags: css, angular, typescript, loops

The idea is to alternate between 2 object's image property received from an API and displaying the picture for a determined time in the object and looping over the entire array continuously. (Dog shows for 30 seconds, and then cat shows for 10 seconds and repeats sequence).

```
    "data": [
        { 
            "title": "Example",
            "content": [
                {
                  "FirstPart": {
                    "img": "dog.jpg",
                    "duration": "30"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "SecondPart": {
                    "img": "cat.jpg",
                    "duration": "10"
                  }
                }
            ]
      }
```

Here is my attempt :

```
    getInfo() {
      let duration: number;
      let imgText: string;

      const content = data['content'];
      for (const part of content) {
        startCountdown(part.duration);
      }
    }

    startCountdown (seconds: number) {  
       let counter = seconds;
       const intv = setInterval(() => {
          console.log(counter);
          counter--;

             if (counter < 0 ) {
                clearInterval(intv);
                console.log('Ding!'); // This should be where I put my image
             }}, 1000);}
```

So here are my two issues :

1. This solution starts the timer for both object at the same time. How can I control it so that the next timer starts when the first one finishes?
2. If I want to loop over the array again, my browser starts crashing because of an never ending loop. I don't see how I can loop over an array without doing this even though I know it's wrong. How do I tackle this problem?

   ```
   // Instead of looping the over the array once like stated above
     for (const part of content) { 
       startCountdown(part.duration);
     }

   // I would of tried to re run the loop 
     for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i ++) {
        if (i === content.length) { 
           i = 0 ;
        }
        <-- There was a whole bloc of code I had inserted here in my original code 
        but it just never worked because of my for loop above -->//
     }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` and call it in the end of the handler:

```js
const content = [
  { "img": "dog.jpg", "duration": "2" },
  { "img": "cat.jpg", "duration": "5" },
  { "img": "bird.jpg", "duration": "3" },
  { "img": "horse.jpg", "duration": "1" },
];

startCountdown(content, 0);

function startCountdown(content, index) {
  console.log('show!', index, content[index]);

  setTimeout(() => {
    startCountdown(content, (index + 1) % content.length);
  }, content[index].duration * 1000);
}
```

Note that I did simplify your object a bit.

Comment: I don't really understand this part if you could clarify.               
       `startCountdown(content, (index + 1) % content.length); `  I believe it's a **modulo**?          How does it work for the infinite loop? I see in the code snippet it does run forever.

Comment: I guess you mean the modulo sign (`%`)?

Comment: That is just a simple trick to compute the next index number. You have 2 items in the array (`content.length === 2`), so you can access only index `0` and `1`. By using modulo 2, you can always get only `0` or `1`. So for example in second iteration, you will have `index === 1`, and by doing `(index + 1) % 2`, you will get `0`.

Comment: This way it supports more than 2 items in the array (if you have 5, then this formula will give you `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` and then again start from `0` as `(4 + 1) % 5 = 0`.

Comment: I see, that is really useful. Thank you so much ! Would that be preferred over for loops to have more control over the loop?

Comment: Well I guess this is better (and simpler) approach for what you want. For loop is synchronous, and you want your code to execute asynchronously.